# How to define value for C++ preprocessor directives during compile time?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a following code:

```
int main() {

#ifdef NEWMETHOD
    val = new_method("hello world!");
#else
    val = old_method("hello world!");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

How can I define NEWMETHOD during compile time?

Comment: Most compilers will take `-D` to define a macro: `g++ -DNEWMETHOD yourfile.cpp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either

- Define it by inserting

  ```
  #define NEWMETHOD
  ```

  into the source code before using it or
- Add `-DNEWMETHOD` to your compiler call (works with all popular compilers including GCC, clang and MSVC).

  Depending on your build system you might want to add that to the `CFLAGS` (C) or `CXXFLAGS` (C++) environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to write

```
#define NEWMETHOD
```

before you do the `#ifdef` check.

Of course, then you wouldn't need to write the `#ifdef` in the first place.

If you want to define the macro without changing the source code, you can pass it in during compilation with the `-D` flag, like this:

```
g++ -DNEWMETHOD main.cpp
```

Obviously, replace the specific compiler command, and file name.

Comment: Write it where? Under what conditions? This doesn't explain anything.

Comment: But you haven't. If you can put the definition immediately above the condition, the condition is likely entirely pointless and should just be removed. Instead, other options (like a compiler flag) are more likely to be useful. Sometimes keeping a "switch" around can be useful even if it's right there with the condition, but then it would be worth explaining what those occasions might be.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Also true, added the suggestion.